# Fitting with roots of transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving, fitting

I'm new to this community and my first question probably reflect my lack of confidence with *Mathematica*.

My problem is the following: I find the roots of a transcendental equation dependent on a parameter, let's say $x = \cos(\alpha x)$, And compare these roots with a set of assigned values via an error function (e.g. sum of the absolute value of the difference between each root and the corresponding fixed value). I want to minimize the outcome of the error function varying the parameter $\alpha$, in order to get a value for $\alpha$ such that the transcendental roots lie the closest possible to the assigned values.

I'm basically trying to fit data (the assigned values) with the roots of an equation depending on a parameter. I think that it should work in this way:

1. Find roots of transcendental equation
2. Error function outputs an error given by confronting the calculated roots with data
3. Some minimization, varying the parameter until you get to a value for it that minimize the error function.

The minimization function should than be able to repeat the process from point number 1 at every change of the parameter, but I couldn't find any simple function doing that. I'm not sure if you can do that with the fitting function I've already seen, like `FindFit`, and I'm not sure I'm looking at the problem the right way.
Is there an easy way to do that with *Mathematica's* function?

Comment: Thanks for a well-formatted first question, and welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand your question.

Here is a table of values of `{alpha, f[alpha]}`

```
mybasedata = Table[{α, x /. NSolve[{x == Cos[α x] && 0 < x < 2 π/α}, x][[1]]}, {α, 0.1, 2, .1}] // Quiet
```

Here is the functional fit:

```
myfit[α_] = Fit[mybasedata, {1, α, α^2, α^3}, α]
```

(*
1.02718 - 0.2184 α - 0.112612 α^2 + 0.0475883 α^3
*)

Here is the full training data:

```
mytrainingdata = Table[{α, myfit[α]}, {α, .1, 2, .1}];
```

Here is some fake test data:

```
mytestdata = Table[{α, RandomReal[]}, {α, .1, 2, .1}];
```

Here is an error score:  the variance of the values of `mytrainingdata` and `mytestdata`:

```
myError = Variance[mytrainingdata[[All, 2]] - mytestdata[[All, 2]]]
```

(* 0.108539 *)

This overall code can be streamlined significantly (since we needn't use the values of alpha in several steps) but let us know if this is what you're seeking.